# Reconfiguring an app built with an old version of Rails with Turbolinks into Rails 7 with Turbo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had built a twitter clone using an older version of Rails and the Turbolinks library that went with it. I am now trying to rebuild that project using the newer Rails, version 7, and find that with it I have to deal with Turbo instead of Turbolinks. I have not had any success implementing the required modifications in my project such that the tweets are displayed in turbo fashion. This is how that functionality worked previously:

The `tweets_controller.rb` created the tweet and sent out its data in a turbo_stream format

```
  def create
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params.merge(user: current_user))

    if @tweet.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path }
        format.turbo_stream
      end
    end
  end
```

The data from the controller was sent to `views/tweets/create.turbo_stream.erb`

```
<%= turbo_stream.prepend "tweets" do %>
  <%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", locals: { tweet_presenter: TweetPresenter.new(@tweet) } %>
<% end %>
```

... from which it was dispatched to `presenters/tweet_presenter.rb` to be processed before sending it to be displayed:

```
class TweetPresenter
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers 

  def initialize(tweet:, current_user:)
    @tweet = tweet
    @current_user = user
  end

  attr_reader :tweet, :current_user

  delegate :user, :body, :likes, :likes_count, :retweets_count, to: :tweet
  delegate :username, :display_name, :avatar, to: :user
```

... and finally the tweet was sent to be displayed at `tweets/tweet.html.erb` wrapped in the following tag:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(tweet_presenter.tweet) do %>
```

This is not working now with Turbo. I get the following error message in the console:

```
Started POST "/tweets" for ::1 at 2023-04-13 14:29:24 -0700
Processing by TweetsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "tweet"=>{"body"=>"GSd"}, "commit"=>"Tweet"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:2:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Tweet Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "tweets" ("user_id", "body", "created_at", "updated_at", "likes_count", "retweets_count") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["body", "GSd"], ["created_at", "2023-04-13 21:29:24.980899"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-13 21:29:24.980899"], ["likes_count", 0], ["retweets_count", 0]]
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  Rendering tweets/create.turbo_stream.erb
  Rendered tweets/create.turbo_stream.erb (Duration: 27.5ms | Allocations: 1184)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms | Allocations: 5382)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: tweet, current_user)):
    1: <%= turbo_stream.prepend "tweets" do %>
    2:   <%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", locals: { tweet_presenter: TweetPresenter.new(@tweet) } %>
    3: <% end %>
  
app/presenters/tweet_presenter.rb:5:in `initialize'
app/views/tweets/create.turbo_stream.erb:2:in `new'
app/views/tweets/create.turbo_stream.erb:2
app/views/tweets/create.turbo_stream.erb:1
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Much obliged!

Comment: This code here doesn't actually have much to do with Turbolinks or Turbo Drive which replaces it. What Turbolinks/Drive does is "ajaxify" your entire app by making all your links send XHR requests and then rebuilding the document with the fetched data. Turbo Stream and Frames doesn't actually have an equivilent pre Rails 7. Earlier versions had Rails UJS which was kind of a poor mans SPA framework but almost always turned into complete shit show due to it's lack of  architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it may be an argument passing issue.

Your TweetPresenter takes 2 **keyword** arguments and both are required:

```rb
  def initialize(tweet:, current_user:)
```

But you initialize the presenter without a keyword arg:

```
tweet_presenter: TweetPresenter.new(@tweet)
```

That's why you see the error:
`ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: tweet, current_user)):` (Note the "*required keywords*" in that message.). This in turn causes the surrounding view to fail.

Try changing that section to something like:

```
tweet_presenter: TweetPresenter.new(tweet: @tweet, current_user: current_user)
```

---

Also I think there may be a secondary error in your TweetPresenter.

```rb
  def initialize(tweet:, current_user:)
    @tweet = tweet
    @current_user = user
  end
```

Line 3 there tries to assign `user` to instance variable `@current_user`, but this method doesn't take a `user` it takes a `current_user` keyword argument.  It should be: `@current_user = current_user`

Comment: Thank you very much @tgf. That took care of it.